# Removing a Structure group from URL

Tags: 2013, structuregroups

We have a requirement to Not to display a structure group in URL. For example our cme looks like

```
Home
    Articles
        Publications
        Solutions
        Technnology
            Page.aspx
```

So currently for page.aspx URL is forming as follow

http://www.example.com/Articles/Technology/Page.aspx

Our requirement is to have a URL like below (No Articles in URL)
http://www.example.com/Technology/Page.aspx

To Implement it the solution I have are as follows

1. Do not use Article structure group in CM, put all SG at Home Level only.
   This is the easiest approach. But Dont want to implement it.
2. Use URL rewrite logis to remove about from url.
3. Extend storage extension to publishish pages/SG on root level.
   Difficult and may also make exiting links invalis.

I want to learn from you all, is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you edit your question and explain a bit more details about why you have this requirement? Like, why is the Structure Group `Articles` in the CM and why don't you want it part of the URL?
Also what publishing model/template technology are you using (since that will dictate what sort of answer you need)?

Comment: Indeed, the "don't want to implement it" on the most obvious solution is remarkable and needs further elaboration. Note that the sole purpose of SGs is to reflect the (virtual) site structure. It seems weird to create a SG structure which doesn't reflect the site structure. You may also get uniqueness issues from doing that.